# How do I use IFF in SSRS 2012

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am trying to get a average of a cycle times for all Serial numbers where cycle time <10 .

Here is the expressions I am using
=Avg(Fields!CycleTime.Value) IFF ( CycleTime<10),"Fields!CycleTime.Value","0")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got your syntax from but it's all wrong....

For a start it's IIF not IFF

The expression you need is

```
=AVG(IIF(Fields!CycleTime.Value <10, Fields!CycleTime.Value,Nothing))
```

**The explanation if you are interested**

The inner part simply evaluates each record to either it's value if it's <10 or `nothing` if it's >=10.

We then just take an average of these results.

**Note** We can't return a 0 for the records that are 10 or greater because this would cause them to be included in the average. By returning `Nothing` the AVG function will ignore these.

To illustrate lets say we had the following values

```
5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
```

If our IIF function returned zeros for values >=10 then we would get these results

```
5,6,7,8,9,0,0,0,0
```

The sum of these is 35 but we have 9 values for the AVG would be 3.89

If we change the IIF function to return `Nothing' then the results would look like this.

```
5,6,7,8,9, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing
```

again our sum is 35 but AVG ignores the `nothing` values so divides the result by 5 giving us an average of 7.